# Storing jQuery within a variable then alerting it out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This doesn't seem to work for me:

```
var navListLength = $('nav ul#nav-list li').length();
alert(navListLength);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:

**Some HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul id="nav-list">
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#top">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: length() should be length

Comment: length isn't a function

Comment: I'd say the worst thing you're doing is not using the console to debug. Second thing would be to call properties like functions ?

Comment: While all that is true, the question doesn't really deserve a downvote. Maybe just for not having searched for it before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `length` is not a method, but a property.

Try

```
var navListLength = $('nav ul#nav-list li').length;
alert(navListLength);
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Still new to this. That was super simple. Any reason why it'd return 0 instead of 3? I have 4 list items in the HTML. Triple checked all my spelling.

Comment: @dustindowell22 - Try to use the debugger to find the problem.